# laravel domain root is returning blank page with dot

Tags: php, laravel, apache, laravel-5

When I uploaded the project to the apache server. When I log into domain.com, a blank white page appears. But if I log into domain.com/index.php, it works fine. It also works fine when I log in to domain.com/home, but when I log in to domain.com, there is a blank white page with a dot.

!! I don't have problems if I run it with php artisan serve.

I'm having this problem in the apache server www / html folder

Comment: it could be worse, there could be 3 dots ...

Comment: have you checked if there is an `index.html`

Comment: Try checking the page headers to see if the page is coming from laravel or apache

Comment: in your apache config, did you check if it is required or not the index name in the url?

Comment: Thanks  i deleted index.html file and fix my problem